# How to use the Eclipse Toolkit with the new AWS update (Expansion of AWS Lambda states to all functions)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, eclipse, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am very new to AWS and at the company I work for, I have been uploading Java Lambda functions to AWS using the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse. I simply right-click the project in Eclipse > click `AWS Lambda` > click `upload function to AWS Lambda`.

From there, my project is uploaded to Lambda. However, I received an email from AWS that mentioned they are rolling out changes that may have an `impact certain workflows that attempt to invoke or modify a function shortly after a create or an update action`. According to the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/coming-soon-expansion-of-aws-lambda-states-to-all-functions/) they sent in the email, the changes won't take effect until December 6th but they are giving us the chance to prepare by opting in early.

So my question is, how come when I opt-in to these changes as mentioned how in the documentation, I get an error stating:

```
Failed to upload project to Lambda

The operation cannot be performed at this time. An update is in progress for resource arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:function:my-demo: xxxxxx 
(Service: AWSLambda; Status Code 409; Error Code: ResourceConflictException; Request ID: xxxxxx)
```

If I DO NOT opt-in to the changes, my lambda function can still be uploaded as it has been for the last year, straight from Eclipse. When I choose to opt-in, the lambda function can no longer be updated.

To `opt-in`, I simply add `aws:states:opt-in` to the function's description (as stated in the documentation I linked)

Hopefully someone with more experience can shed some light on this. Will the lambda functions be okay when December 6th rolls around if I do nothing? Or when December 6th is here, will I have the same issue I have right now, which is that I cannot upload the function from Eclipse anymore?

EDIT: To be more specific, I would like to be able to upload the lambda function to AWS using the Toolkit in Eclipse. This works now, but not when I use `aws:states:opt-in` to opt-in. Then it fails to upload. Why? What can I do to upload this function with the new AWS changes that will take effect December 6th?

**EDIT #2** A more in-depth view of the error: [image: error log]

It is the same problem as this question that has no answers: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661631/failed-to-upload-project-to-lambda-when-trying-to-upload-java-code-to-aws-from)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok, added info to be more clear

Comment: You are dealing with a Tool that may or may not work. To get around this issue, learn how to build a JAR file from your Java Lambda project and manually upload the JAR to the Lambda AWS Management console that will always deploy your Lambda function without a  tool blocking you.

Comment: Okay let’s say I want to upload the project to AWS lambda as a zip file. How do I create this zip file from Eclipse? Is it as simple as exporting > archive file > export as zip using all directories in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to not use the Eclispe Toolkit anymore. Instead, I put all of the external jar files inside `src/main/resources` and wrote a batch script that will add those files to local maven repo like this. Example of two of the lines in my batch script. I do this for each file:

```
EHCO starting
CALL mvn install:install-file -Dfile="./src/main/resources/routines.jar" -DgroupId=talend-jars -DartifactId=test-eenav-routine -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
CALL mvn install:install-file -Dfile="./src/main/resources/currenttalendproject_0_1.jar" -DgroupId=talend-jars -DartifactId=test-eenav-main-talend-jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

CALL mvn package
```

At the end of the above of script I call `CALL mvn package` which produces my shaded JAR which can be uploaded to AWS Lambda.

Here is the pom file that shows my configuration for shaded plugin as well as the two dependencies I added to the local maven repo:

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>Demo-SHADED</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>talend-jars</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-eenav-routine</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>talend-jars</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-eenav-main-talend-jar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Toolkit for Eclipse hasn't been updated since 2018, it doesn't have an update to fix this problem.  But it is still possible to deploy to a Lambda function, it just requires 3 steps instead of 1.

1. Deploy from the Amazon Web Service menu in Eclipse as usual ("Upload function to AWS Lambda...")
2. When the error dialog appears with ResourceConflictException, go to the S3 bucket that the AWS Tooklit uploads the zip file to.  The updated zip file should be there. Copy the S3 URL for that file to the clipboard.
3. On the AWS Lambda function webpage for your Lambda function, there is a "Code" tab with a "Code Source" box. On the right, click on "Upload from" then "Amazon S3 Location". Paste in the S3 Url.  The deployment will complete OK.

Answer (score 0):

I am still using the Eclipse toolkit for creating the Java lambda projects but I can not deploy with it. I use maven to create the jar then I upload using the AWS CLI.

The Eclipse toolkit have been abandoned for so long time that it is really behind.